# Start browser, enter url, enter username and password with script or vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have good experience with vb.net but almost none writing script. I think the solution to my need is a script. I want to click on a shortcut on the desktop and have the script/code start the default browser then enter the url, select login, then it should enter the username and password. I am asking for an article to read to get me started in the right direction. I am sure this task has been done many times.

Comment: *"I think the solution to my need is a script"*. Then why is this question tagged VB.NET and nothing else?

Comment: Excellent idea, but a "script" in what language?

Comment: Couldn't you just put a link to the login page in the startup?

Comment: Just FYI, many popular websites nowadays put extra measures in place to detect exactly this kind of automation because it's abused so much by bots, so whatever path you choose, research it thoroughly since you may be more likely to trigger a captcha.  For people big into automation, Ubot Studio is popular.  You might be able to rig something up with AutoIt.